# Resource initialization during static initialization?

Tags: java

I'm working on my first Swing application and now come up with a dilemma: Perform bootstrapping and resource initialization during static initialization or after starting actual execution. What do I mean... I've got `Application` singleton:

```
public enum Appliation{
    INSTANCE;

    private static void initResources(){
        //init resources
    }

    private Application(){
         initResources();
    }

    public void run(){
        //display the gui
    }

    //remainders omitted
}
```

So the `main` method would look like

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Application app = Application.INSTANCE;
    app.run();
}
```

Or maybe I initialize the resources by hand after it's started and then run it. What would be the logically right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, avoid making `Application` a singleton with `enum`. If it's a normal class you can perform initialization in the constructor.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application app = new Application();
    app.run();
}
```

This allows `main()` to control when the class is initialized, which is good for many reasons. If initialization is slow, `main()` controls when and on what thread it happens. If exceptions are possible, `main()` can catch them. `main()` can also set up the thread default exception handler, configure logging, or do other startup tasks that ought to precede `Application`'s initialization.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a `singleton`, I would personally proceed by `lazy initialization` as you could get exceptions while initializing your resources such that if you implement it as a simple singleton you could get exceptions during the static initialization of the class which leads to bug hard to find.

```
public class Application {

    private Application() {
        initResources();
    }

    private void initResources(){
        //init resources
    }

    public static Application getInstance() {
        return ApplicationHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public void run(){
       //display the gui
    }

    //remainders omitted

    /**
     * Static inner class used to lazy initialize the Application, it will
     * be loaded only on Application.getInstance() such that if it fails,
     * you will easily understand that is while initializing the Application
     */
    private static class ApplicationHolder {
        private static final Application INSTANCE = new Application();
    }
}
```

Then your `main` method would look like this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Application app = Application.getInstance();
    app.run();
}
```